# How to get full date from string without having the actual month in the string in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Is there any way to get the full date from a string that does not actually contain the month?

i am given the date in a format of `Wednesday 16th` and need to add this to my database with a month,

The application i am making is for lifestyle couriers and they get their manifests in that format and have the last 2 months available, so i need to find out the month?

Comment: There will always be many Wednesday 16ths on different months and different years. Thus, in general it is not possible. However, if as you say, you only need to know *was it last month or the month before that*, then yes, this is possible.

Comment: Toastrackenigma: The question is valid. He is only talking about the last two months, not of the whole year. I this case it could be that there will not be no second "wednesday 16th" in a timespan of three months.

Comment: Also it's not about **loops** it's about what the loops does and how fast. I just did some testing and found a Wednesday on day 13 that is 13 months back. This took my code 0.005 seconds @php 7.2. https://3v4l.org/qBLNS/perf#output I'm not going to try to do the same with the "correct" answer but if one month back takes 0.5 seconds I can only imagine the wait. If you really want to optimize your code then don't think about "loops = bad", try and see or see which uses the least amount of unnecessary variables and function calls. You can have 20 million loops and they may still perform better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$date = 16;
$day = "Wednesday";

$oneMonthAgo = explode(" ",date("m Y F",strtotime("-1 month")));
$twoMonthsAgo = explode(" ",date("m Y F",strtotime("-2 months")));

if (date("l",strtotime($date."-".$oneMonthAgo[0]."-".$oneMonthAgo[1]))==$day) {
    echo "Last month: ".$oneMonthAgo[2];
}
else if (date("l",strtotime($date."-".$twoMonthsAgo[0]."-".$twoMonthsAgo[1]))==$day) {
    echo "Month before last: ".$twoMonthsAgo[2];
}
else {
    echo "Not valid";
}
?>
```

### Explanation

Because you are using PHP, there is an easy way to do this. In other languages, you would have to use a [weekday algorithm](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node73.html).

In PHP, we can convert a properly formatted string into a time, from which we can then derive date information. Examples of a properly formatted string is `-1 month` or `-2 months`, which return time objects for the previous month or the month before that, respectively.

Using the `date()` function, we can get the month, year and textual month values for those months. We delimiter these by a space, so that we can explode these values into an array after they are found. Thus, we now have two arrays, `$oneMonthAgo` and `$twoMonthsAgo`, which both contain their month's respective number, year and textual month at the `0`, `1` and `2` indexes respectively.

Now, we can create another time, by appending the date that we are looking for (`$date`) onto these values, with the proper delimiters in-between (when using `-` as the delimiters, PHP assumes a `d-m-Y` format, when using `/` PHP assumes a `m-d-Y` format). Then, by passing that through another `date()` function, we can find the data that we are looking for: the textual day that took place at that date. Now we can simply compare that to the day that we are looking for, `$day`. If the textual day is the same, then this is the month which we are looking for, so we can print out the full textual month.

We do this in an `if` / `else` statement for both months, and if we still haven't found it, assume that the date is invalid.

### Notes

- References to the PHP functions used can be found on the PHP Manual: [`date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [`strtotime()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [Valid dates for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Comment: This may work. But I don't understand the explode part. Why explode the date and then rebuild it in the if() one line below?

Comment: @Andreas Because otherwise you would need to have a total of ***six*** calls to `date()`

Comment: No you wouldn't.

Comment: This is an extremely slow code. With the same input this code is more than 0.5 seconds slower than mine. https://3v4l.org/bjlOk/perf#output vs. https://3v4l.org/vrrUY/perf#output

Comment: @Andreas Your answer has a problem though. If there is invalid input, it won't stop after two months (the limit that OP defined), but will instead keep going until such a date is found (and thus could be months / years off). Also, while your statement that yours runs 0.5 seconds faster, this is only for PHP 7, on PHP 5 they run at about exactly the same speed. I agree that the `explode` bit could be improved in my answer, but yours has a potentially catastrophic bug and no explanation whatsoever as to how it works.

Comment: i choose this as the answer but @andreas wants to cry about it, this is far better and will give me the month rather then adding extra code to Andreas to get the month, about it being 0.5 seconds slower i can see no real difference when running it against 63 queries, takes about a second to compute all 63 but that's down to the server i'm getting the manifests from being slow not your code..

Comment: @toastrackenigma if that is a catastrophic bug then I'd say you are way off. It's only another condition on the while loop and there is no more "catastrophic bug". Just add `|| $x <=2` and it will  stop at maximum 2. Your code will always use unnecessary power to both date(), strtotimetime() and explode() if the answer is one month back. This code will always prepare unnecessary data. What do you mean with no explanation? Do you want me to tell you how the bits change in computer memory? What more can I say? It loops back to find what is searched for?

Comment: Can you answer me what I did not explain about my answer?

Comment: @Andreas All I meant was you did not explain how it works to OP. You don't need to tell us "*how the bits change in computer memory*", just a little explanation (or at least links) as to what `strtotime` and `date` do, and a bit more explanation about the basic algorithm. Anyway, our code is about the same: I believe that we both do **two** calls to date, but yours has the possibility to do three or more? Explode is resource intensive though, so it should even out, and ***does*** in PHP 5 (mine is 1ms slower there). Thus, in PHP 7 mine taking so much longer must be due to a memory leak in PHP.

Comment: In my opinion if anyone needs to know what strtotimetime is or what date is then they can and should Google it. Although I sometimes do explain it, it's not necessary. In my code it has three parts, input, loop, and output. Inputs and outputs should not need explaination, and the loop was explained. I believe there is more to why yours is slower. Your code is not predicable by the compiler. Loops (especially small and simple) will be cached in cpu memory and depending on the language sometimes performed in chunkes thus making it faster. Normal code is not predicable and the cpu has to grab ->

Comment: data and functions from memory. So even if the code looks simpler to a human it doesn't mean it's simpler for a computer. This is WET/DRY coding. We Enjoy Typing (your code), or Don't Repeat Yourself. There is plenty of documentation about wet and dry if you want to read about it. Here you can see an perfect example of this. My code loops back 13 months quicker than yours do one month. https://3v4l.org/qBLNS/perf#output it's not a coincidence.

Comment: @Andreas Personally for something this trivial, I'm not sure that any of this really matters. I used the tool that you provided to run speed tests for the 8th of Thursday (which was in June) for both of our programs, and they are almost identical in terms of performance, which is odd since it is a harder task for your program (another loop) and my program should take the same amount of time (as it always computes both months). Thus, something odd is happening with that tool. You can take a look here https://3v4l.org/2iCMF/perf#output and here https://3v4l.org/V496v/perf#output

Comment: No I think you missed my point. My code will not run one loop at the time, I have no proof about it but I saw a video explaining how loops run more than one loop at the time in some languages, and I believe most newer languages do. That means 1-x number of months back will take the same amount of time. And we know x is more than 13 since the time of Wednesday 13 is about the same. The point is, if you duplicate your code to manage 13 months back what is your time?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not saying that yours is a bad way to do it, and it ***would*** be the right way to do it if you were running 13 months back - it would be ridiculous to do it my way for that. All I'm saying is that in this particular scenario, where we only have to loop for two months, they're about the same. With regards on your thing about the loops, your code will still **have** to run each of the `date` functions, because otherwise how will it know when to end the loop? Thus, you run at most three `date` functions, and I run two (but also `explode`), so it should be about the same.

Comment: Yet again you think like a human. Yes it may seem like mine does use date more times than yours. But again, loops are predictable, WET code is not. What is in the loop? It's a UNIX timestamp, an integer. What should happen with the integer? Loop it backwards with one month at the time. What is a month? An integer. So deduct month integer from integer as long as the date output is not weekday name.

Comment: And your code runs the date function three times just to get to one month back. Not two.

Comment: "*It's a UNIX timestamp, an integer. What should happen with the integer? Loop it backwards with one month at the time. What is a month? An integer. So deduct month integer from integer as long as the date output is not weekday name.*" That is literally a call to the `date` function. Computers are not magic. Yes, in some languages loops are optimised well (not sure if this is the case in PHP though), but they still will need to run the condition for something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization. Also yes, my code will need three calls to `date` for one month, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to regard the current and the last two months, I can imagine, that there will be no two day numbers of the same week day in that timespan (that should be proven first).

I would iterate back over the last n days using PHP's date function and try to detect your "Wednesday 16th" where n is the aggregate of month days that date with param "t" returns for the current and the last two months.

If you have your match then, you know the month and the year (the year could be the previous year as well if you start in January or February).

Answer (score -1):

`Yes` and `no`. Since `full date` requires month to be known you need to know what to do with lack of that information. If you "guess" the month (be it current one or random, does not matter), then "yes" is close. If you cannot tell what the month we talk about then answer is `no` (or `random`).

PS: you may need a `year` too...

Answer (score -1):

I use a while loop to loop backwards however many months needed to find what is searched for.

```
$date = 16;
$day = "Wednesday";
$x=0;

$start = date("Y-m-") . $date;

While(date("l", strtotime($start ."-" .$x . "months")) != $day){
    $x++;
}
Echo $x . " months ago.";
// Or to output the date:
//Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start ."-" .$x . "months"));
```

https://3v4l.org/vUYeX

This will output 0 months ago.
But if input $date= 15; it will output 5 months ago (March 2017).